# When move to other page by using ngRoute, Angular parameters are unknown in html

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, routeparams

I have Menu.html page that shows list of dishes. By clicking the image of each dish, I want to guide the user to dishdetail.html page. But in dishdetail.html, angular parameters are unknown.

Menu.html:

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
            <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in dishes| filter:filtText">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#/menu/{{dish._id}}">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                    <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{dish.label}}</span>
                    <span class="badge">{{dish.price|currency}}</span>
                    </h2>
                    <p ng-show="showDetails">{{dish.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

dishdetail.html:

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a href="#/menu/{{dish._id}}">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                    </a>
            </div>

            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{dish.label}}</span>
                <span class="badge">{{dish.price|currency}}</span>
                </h2>
                <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

and app.js:

```
'use strict'
 angular.module('confusionApp',  ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)  {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/menu',  {   //  route   for the menu    pag
           templateUrl :    'menu.html',    controller      :   'MenuController'
    })

    .when('/menu/:id',  {   //  route   for the dish    details pag
           templateUrl :    'dishdetail.html',  controller      :   'dishDetailController'
    })

    .otherwise('/menu');
}]);
```

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
      'menuFactory', function($scope, $routeParams, menuFactory) {

        var dish= menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));
        $scope.dish = dish;
  }]);
```

and services.js:

```
'use strict'
 angular.module('confusionApp')

   .factory('menuFactory',function(){

        var menufac = {};

        var dishes=[
        {
        _id:0,
        name:'Uthapizza',
        image:'images/uthapizza.png',
        category:'main',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza topped with cerignola olives, ripe vine charry tomatoes, vidalia onion, Guntour chillies.'
        },
        {
          _id:1,
        name:'Elaicheesecake',
        image:'images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category:'appetizer',
        label:'New',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza topped with cerignola olives, ripe vine charry tomatoes, vidalia onion, Guntour chillies.'
        }];

        menufac.getDishes = function(){
            return dishes;
        };

        menufac.getDish = function(index){
            return dishes[index];
        };

        return menufac;
    });
```

Comment: Instead of calling $routeparams in your factory method call try;
var id = $routeparams.id;
var dish = menuFactory.getDish(id);

Comment: @Tom Johnson no need converting id to integer before send to getDish() method?

Comment: I've never had the need to do it, but I don't see the harm in doing it - it'll give you extra error handling if you have it which is useful :)

Comment: @TomJohnson There was no change. angular parameters are still  unknown

Comment: Stick a 'debugger;' in your menufac.getDish function, and use F12 to open developer mode in your webbrowser. Then use F10 to cycle through the functions - if the debugger is getting hit we'll know if there's an issue with calling your factory.

Comment: My factory work well, Because when i use '$scope.dish = menuFactory.getDish(3);' instead of $routeParameter  and enter dishdetail.html in browser, i saw my result. But, by using routeParam and try show detal page by clicking in image in menu.html, my angular parameters become empty.

Comment: Oh I understand, it seems that routeparams isn't receiving your ID, perhaps it's because your property variable is _id which could possibly be a private variable. Switch your property name from _id to id, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your object properties, "_id" is a private property - an underscore before a property/variable means that it is private and that only the controller/script can see it.

A way around would be to change your object property "_id" to "id".

Comment: I was involved with this problem for several days. I used 'var id = $routeparams.id; var dish = menuFactory.getDish(parseInt(id,10));' and change 'id' to '_id'. But the problem is not resolved. Today, I only change this line of code: 'var dish= menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));' and the problem was solved by itself. Finally, I did not understand what the problem was?